# Zend Framework 2 - Annotation forms - Multiple forms in one view

Tags: php, forms, annotations, zend-framework2, zend-view

I'm using `ZF2` and `AnnotationForms`. This worked great for me until now.

I have this exception that I want to display three forms in one view.

Basically I do the following:

```
<form>
  <?php for field in form1: echo field ?>
  <?php for field in form2: echo field ?>
  <?php for field in form3: echo field ?>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My problem is that some of these forms have fields with the same name (eg. "city"). So some of the input data gets lost.

I thought about renaming the fields (name-attribute in HTML) but then the mapping in the action with `$entity->setData()` won't work...

Does anyone has an idea how I can solve this without the need to build my whole form staticly in plain html?

Comment: Ultimately this sounds like to be a case of where you'd actually want to use Zend\Form\Fieldset instead of Zend\Form\Form for the separate "Entities" - though i can't give you any concrete help on Annotation Stuff :S

Comment: See http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/07/04/new-zendform-features-explained/

Comment: Hm, seems like something I could use. But as always: Is there a way to combine it with annotation forms?

Comment: From what i can tell by the Code, the AnnotationBuilder only supports the `createForm()` method of `Zend\Form\Factory` and not the `createFieldset()`. Only going by this i would assume: **NO**. But i still suggest heading over to #zftalk and ask there, Maks3w, Bakura and Mwop himwelf might be the persons to ask, i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ComposedObject annotation, this will actualy create fieldset from some other model/entity file.
It's very good explainded here: http://devblog.x2k.co.uk/using-the-composedobject-zend-framework-2-form-annotation/